# React-Router Link needs to be clicked twice when using the render methods on Route

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom

After searching online I found several answers, none of them helped me, nor could I figure out what is the problem in my case.

I Have a simple Auth flow :

App.js

```
  const App = ({ currentUser, checkUserSession }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    checkUserSession();
  }, [checkUserSession ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/homepage" component={HomePage} />
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={() =>
            currentUser ? <Redirect to="/homepage" /> : <SignInSignUpPage />
          }
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```

HomePage

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <HomePageComponent/>
    );
};

export default withRouter(HomePage);
```

HomePageComponent

```
const HomePageComponent = ({ dispatch , history }) => {
  return (
        <div
          className="homepage-container--header-link"
          onClick={() => {
            dispatch(signOutStart());
            history.push('/')
          }}
        >
          {" "}
          Sign-Out
        </div>
  );
};

export default withRouter(connect()(HomePageComponent));
```

What happens is that the Link from react-router needs to be clicked twice in order to go to the ' / ' path

I can see that the dispatch action is actually been called twice, but the path change is occurring on the second click.

Im also using Redirect base on currentUser value, so the Route should change base on current user value alone (See the App.js)

Comment: `Link` and `onClick` cannot work together. Your second approach is somewhat doable. Can you post complete code using `withRouter`?

Comment: That's right, my bad. Now, do we really need to change the Route manually? as you can see I'm, using Redirect base on the currentUser selector, which gets null using the signOutStart() action

Comment: Yes. Ideally you should not change Route manually.

Comment: whats puzzle's me is that after checking the currentUser when the signOutStart() action is called, I get null - which should handle by the Redirect logic in our App.js and render the SignInSignOutPage, what I think happens is that when using render with redirect it will still use the old props?